# How can I use a list or an array in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that selects into a table a list of data from another table given the date. So to execute the stored procedure, I call the name of the procedure with the date and new table name that the data will be stored into. I do this for as many dates as required. I want to know how to execute the procedure once by placing all the dates and table name in a list/array. See my code below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TablesByDate] 
    (@DaDate varchar(50),
     @TabName nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(max)

    SET @sql = 'select * into ' + @TabName + ' from [23240crNOdrJune] where [create date] = ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @DaDate), '''')  

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
END

--exec TablesByDate '2020-01-06','[Tab01]'
```

Comment: That seems unnecessary, and it's obviously difficult to implement.  Why not just have one big table?

Comment: The data is all coming from one big table, but data is needed for some days that seem to have open items from a match. So the retrieval is required for export to various folks.

Comment: And why don't you just run the procedure multiple times?

Comment: use `IN` ('date1','date2',...). and the dates can be a variable from a dynamic query.

Comment: This sounds interesting, how do i do that?

Comment: You can have table valued SP parameters. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15